# How to make a hidden field with Sencha?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, javascript-framework, sencha-architect

I'm try to make a hidden field on my code with ST 1.1, but I've error in console log.

I have this code:

```
var hddNumClient = new Ext.form.Hidden({
xtype : 'textfield',
name : 'hddNumClient',
id : 'hddNumClient',
value : ''
})
```

I need to create a hidden field and run environment to pass another value response. **Please help me**.

Comment: What is the error shown in the console ? And also, what version of ST do you use (Using too many tags is kinda confusing)?

Comment: May be, you should start moving your app to ST2, as it's more advanced to ST1.x and has no of useful features .. `xtype:'hiddenfield' `

Comment: You can remove the 'xtype' from there, since you are specifically creating an Ext.form.Hidden.  You'll need to paste the actual error console log for more help.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var hddNumClient = new Ext.form.Hidden({

name : 'hddNumClient',
id : 'hddNumClient',
value : ''
})
```

you can not add one element into onther element so you have to remove `xtype:'textfield'`

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to add a hidden field using html code

```
var myvar = new Ext.Container({
items : [ 
      {
      xtype : 'component', 
      html  :'<input type="hidden" name="" value="" id="" >'
     }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sencha uses javascript so you can simply declare a global variable and use it as a hidden field...